# Setting up a validation column using created by column in SharePoint lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, column-validation, list-validation

I am looking to create a validation formula using the `[Created By]` column that comes in default SharePoint lists but cannot understand the right syntax to do so.

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
IF [Column1] = XYZ AND [Created by] = Singh1, Arjun then true 
elseif [Column1] = ABC AND [Created by] = Shukla, Augustika then true
else false
endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it is **not possible** using SharePoint out of the box column/list validation settings because SharePoint list validation formula does not support using `Created By` column (or any other person or group column).

You might need to customize the list forms using Power Apps and perform this validations before save.